# When playing darts, how can I check that my dart didn't hit any other darts?

Tags: binary-search-tree

Imagine a simulation of a [darts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darts) game.  I throw darts at a dart board and they stick in. If I keep throwing, occasionally my latest dart will hit a dart already stuck in the board and bounce out.

I've assumed that each dart is a circle of unit radius. So a 'bounce out' is when the new circle (dart) comes within a distance of 2 of any other 'stuck in' dart.

My problem is that I need to throw 125,000 darts a million times. (It's not really a darts game.) The brute force solution is to just check the distance between the new dart and all existing darts. The time complexity of this approach is O(n^2), and will take days of compute. A seemingly faster way is to use a k-d tree of all thrown darts and remove clashes. That runs in O(log n).

But my implementation of a k-d tree reports that the closest (stuck in node) to any other node is that underlying node, not the next nearest. So all reported distances are always 0.

What can I do? Is there something like a next nearest node k-d tree? Or something completely different?

Comment: *"But my implementation of a k-d tree reports that the closest (stuck in node) to any other node is that underlying node, not the next nearest."* -- If you make the check for the new dart *before* having added that circle to the k-d tree, this problem should not occur.